# How to add a Search button?

Tags: html, css

I have a search input on my site that works by clicking 'Enter', but for some reason I can't figure out how to simply implement a clickable 'Search' button (image button) to go along next to it. How do I do this?

**Here is my search code:**

```
<div id="searchwrap">
    <li id="search">
        <form id="search-form" name="search" action="/products" method="get">
            <input id="search-input" name="search" type="text">
        </form>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: To start with, your HTML in invalid.

Comment: You have `<li>` with no `<ol>` or `<ul>` parent. Also, even if you did have them, you can't nest them inside `<div>` tags.

Comment: @kdm they dont have a button there...

Comment: i dont understand your question

Comment: That's my site and I need a button there haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have a submit image button, you need to add an input of type image to your form:

```
<form id="search-form" name="search" action="/products" method="get">
    <input id="search-input" name="search" type="text">
    <input src="path/to/image" name="submit" type="image">
</form>
```

Comment: Finally somebody who got it right. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This may help you. Search box with the submit image button.

```css
.sidebar .gadget {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 16px 20px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gadget">

  <form method="get" id="search" action="#">
     <span>
        <input type="text" value="Search..." name="s" id="s" />
        <input name="searchsubmit" type="image" src="search.gif" value="Go" id="searchsubmit" class="btn"  />
     </span>
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To implement  a clickable 'Search' button (image button), you need CSS and a submit button.

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .button-search{
            background-image:url('/imagesStatic/searchIcon.png');
            width:70px;
            height:30px;
        }
        .button-search:hover {
           background-image:url('/imagesStatic/searchIconHover.png');   
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="searchwrap">
    <li id="search">
       <form id="search-form" name="search" action="/products" method="get">
        <input id="search-input" name="search" type="text">
        <input type="submit" class="button-search" value="search" />
      </form>
    </li>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

HTML structure from bootstrap:
http://jsfiddle.net/XfzFQ/23/

Comment: What does bootstrap have to do with this question?

Comment: You're right I'll update my answer.